# Mongoose: best way to upsert data defined in conditions array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I trying to find best way for insert/update mongodb documents within one query, without calling save foreach element in result. Is it possible?
This code create document only with setData object.

```
 conditions.idUser = {$in: uids};
    db.Data.update(conditions, {$set: setData}, { multi: true, upsert: true }, function(err) {
```

But I need to save multiple documents, like {idUser : uid1, ..}, {idUser: uid2, ...}

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question.  But, if the filter criteria (i.e., "conditions") you have specified matches multiple documents in the collection, then all of them will be updated, since you have set the "multi" flag to true.  And all documents will have the same update as described by "setData".  Is that what you want or something different?

Comment: Yes, criteria (conditions) matches multiple documents. In this case it contains some array. And I need not only update matched documents, also create ones not only with data specified in setData. Each inserted document should contains one item of array. Seems there are no simple way (without update/insert each element in array separately)

Comment: If you need to update not only matched documents, then I'm afraid it can't be done in a single query.  You could specify the filter criteria as an empty json (i.e., {}) to match all documents if that suits your usecase.